# Legacy SQL Activity and Contacts Dump Transfer

Tags: contacts, import, activities, mysql

Because of the excessive problem that happened to me on SQL, I had to create a new CiviCRM installation.

How can I transfer the existing Individual profiles and Activities in the old CiviCRM database to this new one?

I want to transfer legacy CiviCRM contacts and events to my new system.

Joomla! 3.6.5 - CiviCRM 4.7.17

Answer (score 1):

For contacts and activities you could use the built in import functions If you want to migrate/import entities for which there is usually no gui (such as events), you could try this extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui

I am not sure if it works for profiles though. You could of course use the Rest API as well and for example code a script to import everything but the first time this would probably take a while to get your head around.